# NHProfiler type tool for Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nhibernate, activerecord, profiling, nhprof

In the .NET world there is an awesome product called [NHProfiler](http://nhprof.com/) which provides insights into database activity via NHibernate. It can detect common problems (such as N+1 issues), and report on them from observing the queries that your application runs.

Is there a tool/app/gem that does the same kinda of things for Rails ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is one.
check it this. https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet